# Mongoose full text search not filtering correctly

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

So basically i have model with a bunch of string fields like so:

```js
const Schema: Schema = new Schema(
  {
    title: {
      type: String,
      trim: true
    },
    description: {
      type: String,
      trim: true
    },
    ...
  }
);

Schema.index({ '$**': 'text' });

export default mongoose.model('Watch', Schema);
```

where I index all of them.

Now when I search being that this schema is used as a ref for another model I do a search like this where `user` is an instance of the other model

```
  const { search, limit = 5 } = req.query;
  const query = search && { match: { $text: { $search: new RegExp(search, 'i') } } };

  const { schemaRes } = await user
    .populate({
      path: 'schema',
      ...query,
      options: {
        limit
      }
    })
    .execPopulate();
```

and the searching itself seems to work ok, the problem is when search fields starts to be more specific it seems to me the it does not regard it well.

Example
db

```
  { title: 'Rolex', name: 'Submariner', description: 'Nice' }
  { title: 'Rolex', name: 'Air-King', description: 'Nice' }
```

When the search param is `Rolex` I get both items which is ok but when the search param becomes `Rolex Air-King` i keep on getting both items which to me is not ok because I would rather get only one.

Is there something I could do to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried to get the result via mongo shell or with some other tools? Just for double check.

Comment: I've been using mongodb atlas, but I might have too, do you have another suggestion in the meantime?

Comment: I'm not that knowledgeable about Mongoose but as far as I know, mongodb itself shouldn't have this problem especially for regex searches. If you can output the text your query from `const query = search && { match: { $text: { $search: new RegExp(search, 'i') } }` maybe somebody can find if there is something wrong or not.

Comment: @LeonardoDrici if you are using MongoDB Atlas, you could also mention this in the question. There is Atlas Search (Beta), which is more powerful and might solve your problem. https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/atlas-search/

Answer (score 0):

Returning both items is correct, since both items match your search params, but with different similarity score.

You can output the similarity score to help sorting the result.

```js
user.aggregate([
  { $match: { $text: { $search: "Rolex Air-King" } } },
  { $set: {  score: { $meta: "textScore" } } }
])
// new RegExp("Rolex Air-King", 'i') is not necessary and even invalid,
// as $search accepts string and is already case-insensitive by default
```

The query will return

```
[{
  "_id": "...",
  "title": "Rolex",
  "name": "Air-King",
  "description": "Nice",
  "score": 2.6
},
{
  "_id": "....",
  "title": "Rolex",
  "name": "Submariner",
  "description": "Nice",
  "score": 1.1
}]
```

Since the second result item matches your search query (even partially), MongoDB returns it.

You could use the score to help sort the items. But determining the right threshold to filter the result is complex, as the score depends on the word count as well.

On a side note: You can assign different weights to the fields if they are not equally important
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/control-results-of-text-search/